# MvcSiteMapProvider - Menus intermittently disappear

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, mvcsitemapprovider

I am using the [ASP.NET MVC SiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider) by Maarten Balliauw.

**I display a main navigation and breadcrumb using the helpers. From time to time I've noticed that they totally disappear from the rendered pages.**

In local environment I have to rebuild the project and navigate away from the current page in the browser to get them back. In production, I found that I have to re-upload the site DLL. These "fixes" themselves only work with mixed success.

There is a "slight" pattern, but not confirmed - that problem occurs when you have edited or upload a view.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's some of my code :

portion of sitemap file:

```
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index" key="home">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="About us" controller="about" action="index" key="about">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Our Approach" controller="about" action="approach" url="/about/our-approach" imageUrl="/content/images/ourApproachNavImg.jpg" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>

    <mvcSiteMapNode title="News" controller="news" action="index" key="news" showSubNav="false">
      <mvcSiteMapNode dynamicNodeProvider="XXX.Helpers.NewsItemDynamicNodeProvider, KDC" title="" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
```

helpers:

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(false, true, false)
@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
```

dynamicNodeProvider:

```
public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection()
        {
            var returnValue = new List<DynamicNode>();
            var newsItemService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<INewsItemService>();

            foreach (var item in newsItemService.GetAll(true, true))
            {
                DynamicNode node = new DynamicNode();
                node.Title = item.Title;
                node.Action = "detail";
                node.RouteValues.Add("url", item.Url);
                returnValue.Add(node); 
            }

            return returnValue;
        }
```

The MvcSiteMapProvider in the web.config is per standard and not changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MvcSiteMapProvider v3 had many threading and cache issues that would cause issues like this. [MvcSiteMapProvider v4](http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=mvcsitemapprovider) no longer has these problems because it now has better thread safety and the cached sitemap is made read-only so one user's navigation cannot affect other users.

Comment: I'm using the v4 on MVC4, and I'm still observing the same issue. This is a new introduced error or this answer actually is not the correct answer?

Comment: Do your menus and breadcrumbs disappear, or do they not show up at all? This would be the first report of this happening since the release of v4 if they are vanishing randomly. Please build a small demo project exhibiting the behavior and open a new issue @ Github: https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/new